# Homeomorphism construction

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to construct a homeomorphism $f:A\rightarrow B$ between the sets $A=\{(x,y);|y|>x^2  \text{ and } |y|<10\}$ and  $B=\{(x,y);|y|>x^4  \text{ and } |y|<10\}$. I see  that in some  way  I need to "square" the second  coordinate and take a root of  the first one, but then I have the problem with  staying  within bounds for $y$ described in set $B$. My idea:

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
(\sqrt{x},y^2),& x\geq0,y\geq 0\\
(\sqrt{x},-y^2),& x\geq0,y<0\\
(-\sqrt{|x|},y^2),& x<0,y\geq0\\
(-\sqrt{|x|},-y^2),& x<0,y<0\\
 \end{cases}$$

Here I have good  bounds for $x$ and correct bound $y^2>x^4$ but $y^2<100$ is the problem. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider $u=\sqrt x$ and $v=y^2$ then

$$y>x^2 \implies v>u^8.$$ What happens if we take $u=\sqrt x$ and $v=y?$ In such a case

$$y>x^2 \implies v>u^4.$$ So, one possible homeomorphism is

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
(\sqrt{x},y),& x\geq0\\
(-\sqrt{|x|},y),& x<0
 \end{cases}$$ which is exactly the homeomorphism you had in mind.

Comment: I have modified the homeomorphism because there was a mistake. There was no need to distinguish $y>0$ and $y<0.$